# Adding new functionality to Spreecommerse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am planning to launch a website that acts as a sort of courier service where clients ask my company to find a certain product(for example an action figure) from another country that is not available in their country.

Spreecommerce(including some extensions) offers almost all the functionality that I require.

Shopping Cart, Payment system, CMS, Open Authentication, Commenting system.

One important piece of functionality remains, that is an Enquiry system. with this system customers can request certain products they want.

The form they will use will have the following information:

- Name Description
- Price(optional)
- Barcode(optional)
- Category(Using the same taxon system as products)
- Quantity
- Images
- Comments (using the **spree-contrib/spree_comments**)

My idea is that the user will be presented will have a form which when submitted the admin can view. The admin can view/modify the enquiry and respond using the commenting system. Once the item is located and confirmed, the admin would then create a product and add it to the user’s shopping cart which the user can finalise using the normal spree order check out system.

So my modifications to the system would be:
 - Add the Enquiry form for both client and administrator(administrator can place enquiries in the name of the customer)
 - Make Products private to the users who ordered them
 - Disable the “products” page for users as each product is unique to each user

I am at the point of creating the Enquiry form page. I looked at the spreecommerse documentation and there doesn’t seem to be instructions on adding a new page and integrating it into the system. The documentation focuses more on modifying current pages.

Therefore I decided to view a project that implemented somewhat similar functionality and emulate what it did.

I went with **spree-contrib/spree_static_content**. So what I did was:

Create an enquiry migration using spree_products tables as guidelines with the following information:

- enquiries table
- enquiries_taxons table(Used for “categories”)
- enquiries_variants table(Used for “image uploads”)

Created the following views under app/views/spree/admin (These views are mostly simplified versions of the product views) :

- enquiries/_form.html.erb
- enquiries/edit.html.erb
- enquiries/index.html.erb
- enquiries/new.html.erb
- shared/_enquiries_sidebar_menu.html.erb
- shared/_enquiry_tabs.html.erb

To add the menu item in the admin section:

- app/overrides/add_enquiries_to_admin_main_menu.rb

Created an empty **EnquiriesController** that inherits from **Admin::BaseController**

Created an Enquiries model that inherits from Spree::Base and is loosely based on the Products model.

Things that I am confused about so far are:

- How is CRUD handled?
- Where are the *spree.admin_{name}_url* values being stored?

If there are any tutorials on how to properly create such functionality, it would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, why not use the Spree::Product model as a starting point? Just add custom attributes to that model/table. I suggest this because building your own tables and relations to variants and taxons seems like reinventing the wheel.

You've got a good start here. What you are missing so far is routes

> spree.admin_{name}_url values being stored?

...you don't necessarily need to use the `spree.` namespace for routes if your controllers inherit from `Spree::StoreController` or `Spree::AdminController`. The Spree base controllers provide a bunch of useful CRUD logic. In your case you'd need a routes.rb file that looked something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
end

Spree::Core::Engine.add_routes do
  #public enquiries, e.g. that inherit Spree::StoreController
  get 'enquiries', :to => 'enquiries#index', :as => :enquiries
end

Spree::Core::Engine.add_routes do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :enquiries
  end
end
```

Hottip: check out the spree_scaffold gem. It makes stubbing out models/controllers/view/routes hella quick